# Create MSI with Product Key condition

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer

I'm making MSI with visual studio 2010.
Now, i want to make installer with Prodcut Key.
For begining it can be only one key for all installers.
Can i do it with std tools, or not?
Edit: and user in installation proccess must enter that key, to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Visual Studio Installer Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx).

[Customer Information User Interface Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9h65a3%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [SerialNumberTemplate Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3xwh311%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to accomplish this task.

Also see a similar question asked in [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/62a03f85-b1c2-4608-8b8f-436b72f1c7d6/).

Comment: hm. sorry, forgot. i need user to enter that key due to install, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is additional explanation.

Please follow these steps to add Custom Information dialog and specify `SerialNumberTemplate` property:

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the Setup project.
2. In context menu, click View -> User Interface to open `User Interface Editor`
3. Right-click the Start or Progress node -> click Add Dialog -> select `Custom Information`
4. Configure Custom Information in Properties panel.

Microsoft Visual Studio provides a number of predefined dialog boxes that you can use to display information or gather input during an installation. Please check Installation User Interface Dialog Boxes.